# I am not able to change the URL in css file; by using mod_rewrite in apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The URL is in bold letters where I want to make change...
It should be rewritten to url **/csmmail/lib/webmail/folderTree.gif**

Following is the html snippet...

```
<link href="/csmmail/lib/webmail/folderTree.css?v=bfb38b233d72ba6a690a39394d7c964f"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
x_2az UL, x_2az LI {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
x_2az UL {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px;
}
x_2az LI {
 padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
}
x_2az IMG {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.x_2le {
 margin-right: 3px;
}
.x_2bq {
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.x_2lf {
 background: ***url(/lib/webmail/folderTree.gif***) no-repeat;
 padding: 2px 0 3px 16px;
}
sprite_folder {
}
```

I am new to mod_rewrite; 
I have tried by using in per directory conf file.

```
RewriteEngine   on

Options      +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond     %{HTTP_REFERER} \.(css)$ 

RewriteRule     ^/lib/webmail/folderTree\.gif$ /csmmail/lib/webmail/folderTree.gif [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong, just do :

```
RewriteRule ^/lib/webmail/folderTree\.gif$ /csmmail/lib/webmail/folderTree.gif
```

You can't really rely on HTTP_REFERER since all browser does not set it.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the HTTP_REFERRER to match your .css file.

I guess you are expecting this because you have reference the image in your css file? This is an incorrect assumption.

The referrer will always be the actual page that was loaded in your browser, not the css page.

You can confirm this by using a HTTP sniffing tool like fiddler - http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Try dropping the rewrite condition to see if that works.

Comment: Hi Naraen !!!  I have tried a no of possible combinations. Like by using REQUEST_URI in place of HTTP_REFERER, but its not changing the URL in css.

Comment: I have seen through one of mozilla's add-on (Live HTTP header) that to get the folderTree.gif its generating an HTTP req https://localhost/lib/webmail/folderTree.gif and the referer is https://localhost/csmmail/lib/webmail/folderTree.css